# How to generate a finger print for a public key to validate the public key?

Tags: c, openssl, rsa-key-fingerprint

I need to validate the incoming connection in my application. The incoming connection will be sending a public key and the finger print of the public key. I need to validate this public key by calculating the finger print for the public key and then compare the calculated finger print with the finger print sent by the client. I am not able to find a way to calculate this finger print for the public key. I am using open-ssl library in C platform.

Any help regarding the calculation of this finger print of the public key will be very much appreciated.

Comment: So... you need to hash the public key. Not sure what you're really looking for beyond that. `libcrypto` provides plenty of digest algorithms for doing this, though it would likely be typical for you to use either sha1 or sha256.

Answer (score 0):

I computed SHA1 hash which can be used as fingerprint as following:

```
X509 * cert = ... /*Initialize certificate*/
unsigned char buffer[SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
X509_check_purpose (cert, -1, 0);
/*Copy sha1_hash from the certificate.*/
memcpy(abuffer, rCert->sha1_hash, SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH);
```

I hope this would help you.